# Dragging a WPF Slider thumb with a busy UI thread results in unexpected values

Tags: wpf, multithreading, slider

**EDIT**: There was a lock taken for a long time in the Slider.ValueChanged event. Removing this stops the weirdness.  Bad practice, but the behavior still doesn't make sense to me.  It probably has to do with the message queue, but I'd like an explanation if possible.

When there is significant work on the UI thread*, the WPF Slider does not interact with the mouse as expected.  If I drag the thumb in one direction, the thumb will often advance in front of the mouse cursor, and then go back.  The movement should result in only increasing ValueChanged events, but the events sometimes decrease.  Sometimes this oscillation happens behind the mouse cursor, too. It seems that the mouse's position is predicted by its current velocity.

Can I change this behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

Toggling IsSnapToTickEnabled doesn't help.

*Assigning a large BitmapSource to an Image.  The BitmapSource is created in a worker thread.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFSliderBug.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Image Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" />
    <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="slider1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

using System.Threading;

namespace WPFSliderBug
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private volatile bool m_run = true;
        private double m_sliderValue;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(MainWindow_Closing);
            this.slider1.Minimum = 1;
            this.slider1.Maximum = 30;
            this.slider1.SmallChange = 0.5;
            this.slider1.LargeChange = 0.5;
            this.slider1.TickFrequency = 0.5;
            this.slider1.TickPlacement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TickPlacement.Both;
            this.slider1.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(slider1_ValueChanged);

            Thread t = new Thread((unused_state) =>
            {
                while (m_run)
                {

                    BitmapSource bmp;
                    lock (this)
                    {
                        bmp = ToBitmapSource();
                        bmp.Freeze();
                    }

                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
                    {
                        image1.Source = bmp;
                    }));
                }
            });

            t.Start();
        }

        void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                m_sliderValue = e.NewValue;
            }
        }

        void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {

                m_run = false;
        }

        public BitmapSource ToBitmapSource()
        {
            Random rng = new Random();
            double dpi = 96;
            int bytesPerPixel = 1;
            int width = 2048;
            int height = 2048;

            int stride = ((width * 32 + 31) & ~31) / 8;

            UInt32[] pixelData = new UInt32[width * height];
            for (int i = 0; i < pixelData.Length; ++i)
            {
                double r = rng.NextDouble();
                r = Math.Sin(r) * Math.Cos(r) + Math.Asin(r);
                pixelData[i] = (uint)(r * UInt32.MaxValue);
            }


            BitmapSource bmpSource = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, dpi, dpi,
                PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, pixelData, stride);

            return bmpSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `Ticks`, with `IsSnapToTickEnabled = true`?

Comment: The behavior is the same whether true or false.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this behaviour, I admit that I wasn't doing anything with WPF visuals, simply holding up the UI Thread with a sleep task. Is this something you can replicate in a small C#, XAML app that we can see?

Comment: Sample project? I'd like to see this one in action.  Regardless, my suggestion is to use DataBinding on the Slider.Value property and set a Delay in the binding to ~50ms.  Using ValueChanged can potentially execute a lot of code when dragging the slider.  The BackgroundWorker may be of little consequence after that.

Comment: @Erode, does my sample code exhibit the wonky Slider thumb?